# Relational loops in SQL database design

Tags: sql, database-design

I am making real-estate database and it seems i am doing something wrong, because i have several loops on my design. is it OK or i need to redesign all DB schema?

Here is my Current Schema:

[image]

Comment: What is TownRegionID?  That seems to be the main construct that has a lot of references.  What is it actually representing in this model?

Comment: i think it's good for filter option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "loops" in a database design. Sometimes you do need to traverse data in multiple directions.

Whether this is model right for your application and the application needs is a much more difficult question and one that can't be answered without full details of the application and its data needs.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into your particular design, there is nothing inherently wrong with cyclical relationships in general. Modeling some situations actually requires them (e.g. a "true" 1-to-1 relationship).

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me if your goal is a highly normalized database. I don't see anything wrong with this design.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking the Transaction to different tables that link to an intermediary table that is also linked to the transaction. Sounds kind of redundant?

However, this is what the model is saying. A transaction has a TownRegion, and within that TownRegion, there are Areas, Districts, Streets, and Subways that a transaction could have all, some, or none of (depending on the rules set).

If any of the tables linked to the transaction that could be in different TownRegion's, the database must be changed. And unfortunately, the schema can be difficult to work with with some technologies, but it is the situation that defines the data in any case.

This is a slightly older post here, but I figured I should mention this.